# Are there any issues using reacts useSyncExternalStore with Nextjs and the App router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I was wondering if there are any issues using the useSyncExternalStore hook with Nextjs 13+ and the app directory? I know redux suggests you do no global stores [Redux with nextjs](https://redux.js.org/usage/nextjs#the-app-router-architecture-and-redux) due the the way nextjs handles requests. i was curious if the same would be true for the `useSyncExternalStore` hook doing something like the following:

```
import { useSyncExternalStore } from 'react'

function createStore(initialStore) {
  let store = initialStore
  const listeners = new Set()

  function setStore(newStore) {
    store = newStore
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener(store))
  }

  function subscribe(listener) {
    listeners.add(listener)
    return () => listeners.delete(listener)
  }

  function getStore() {
    return store
  }

  function useStore() {
    return useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getStore)
  }

  return [useStore, setStore, getStore]
}

export const [useStore, setStore, getStore] = createStore({ count: 0 })
```

Are there some gotchas here that I should be aware of because this is technically a global store as well? Any input here would be appreciated before I go and use something that could possibly not work.

Comment: `suggests you do no global stores` that only meant for a server side stores, because if you create a global store on server you might get cached data witch is invalid

Comment: @antokhio So if I only use this in client components with `useStore()` and `setStore()` I should be ok?

Comment: Yea client side should be same as usual